# how to loop over values in servlets and display them in them table?

Tags: java, forms, servlets

I am writing a servlet calculator using doPost method of servlet container.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //show result page

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>SIMPLE CALCULATOR<br><br><br></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<form method = 'post' action = 'calc'>");
        out.println("enter the first number:<br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'text' name='number1'><br><br>");
        out.println("enter the second number:<br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'text' name='number2'><br><br>");
        out.println("enter the operation:<br><br>");
        out.println("<input type ='radio' name = 'op' value = '+'>add<br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'radio' name = 'op' value = '-'>sub<br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'radio' name = 'op' value = '*'>mul<br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'radio' name = 'op' value = '/'>div<br><br>");
        out.println("<input type = 'submit' name = 'result' value = 'submit'><br>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        int a1= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number1"));
        int a2= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number2"));
        String operation = request.getParameter("op");
        int result = 0;
        if(operation.equals("+"))
        {
            result = a1 + a2;
            out.println("The result of " + a1 + " " + operation + " "+ a2 + " = "+ result);
        }
        if(operation.equals("-"))
        {
            result = a1 - a2;
            out.println("The result of " + a1 + " " + operation + " " + a2 + " = "+ result);
        }
        if(operation.equals("*"))
        {
            result = a1 * a2;
            out.println("The result of " + a1 + " " + operation + " " + a2 + " = "+ result);
        }if(operation.equals("/"))
        {
            result = a1 / a2;
            out.println("The result of " + a1 + operation + a2 + " = "+ result);
        }

        out.println("<table border=1>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>first</th>");
        out.println("<th>operation</th>");
        out.println("<th>second</th>");
        out.println("<th>result</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>" + a1 + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + operation + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + a2 + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + result + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        
        out.flush();
    }
```

I wanted to display the values and operations and results everytime I do calculation and click the submit button. What I am now seeing is that only the first calculation values are displayed and when I do the second one It changes the previous one and displays itself.
Expected output is
[image]

I am now seeing
[image]
Anyone has any help?

Comment: I would not code it this way.  I would have  a JSP that display the form and the result.  Then have the servlet compute the result and send the reset back to the JSP page.

Comment: @ChengThao What would the jsp code looks like?

Comment: Let me try to understand what your app is doing.  The user enter two numbers, select an operation and click submit.  It displays the result and the history of previous operations?

Comment: @ChengThao Yes Exactly The question is how do you display the previous results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to use a list of strings to store the history.  If you want a better solution, you could write a class that has first, second, and operator so that you can retrieve each property.  I store the list in the session so that it can be accessed by the JSP page.  I'm just writing a minimal solution.  It's up to you to rewrite it to meet your requirements.

JSP page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<form action="ComputeServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstNumber" size="5"> 
<select name="operator">
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="+">-</option>
  <option value="+">*</option>
  <option value="+">/</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="secondNumber" size="5"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

<c:forEach var="problem" items="${history}">
  <p>${problem}</p>
</c:forEach>
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear">
</form>
```

Servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    
  if (request.getParameter("clear")!=null){
    List<String> history = (List<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("history");
    if (history == null){
      history = new ArrayList<>();
      request.getSession().setAttribute("history", history);
    } else {
      history.clear();
    }     
  } else if (request.getParameter("submit")!=null){
     int first = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstNumber"));
     int second = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("secondNumber"));
     String op = request.getParameter("operator");
     int result = 0;
     switch(op){
       case "+": result = first+second; break;
       case "*": result = first*second; break;
       case "/": result = first/second; break;
       case "-": result = first-second; break;
      }
    List<String> history = (List<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("history");
    if (history == null){
      history = new ArrayList<>();
      request.getSession().setAttribute("history", history);
    }
    history.add("" + first + op + second + "=" + result);
  }
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Output

```
<form action="ComputeServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstNumber" size="5"> 
<select name="operator">
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="+">-</option>
  <option value="+">*</option>
  <option value="+">/</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="secondNumber" size="5"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

  <p>4+5=9</p>
  <p>2+6=8</p>
  <p>3+2=5</p>
  <p>3+2=5</p>

<input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: It shows when I enter numbers and click submit```HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
Type Status Report

Message HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.75```

Comment: Got if fixed thank you.